# Reconstructing image from mask coordinates

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, mask

I have a Boolean mask (i.e. mask1) in a Numpy array. Its shape its as follows:

[image]

Then, I have the following code to extract the x and y coordinates of all the pixels within that mask

```
xy_coords = np.flip(np.column_stack(np.where(mask1 > 0)), axis=1)#getting coordinates of pixels within the mask
```

For my application, I need to reconstruct a new image using these coordinates (so the new image has to have the shape of the mask). I thought that this could be done with a simple for loop as follows:

```
for y in xy_coords[:,0]:
 for x in xy_coords[:,1]:
     new_image[x][y] = 1 #(or any other value)
```

However, the reconstructed new_image has a square shape and not the shape of the original mask.

[image]

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong and help me on what should I do?

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did wrong, that was explained in the other answer.

What to do *instead*: **work with a mask, not with a list of points**

```py
new_image[mask1 > 0] = 1
```

Or if you *must* work with a list of (x,y) points, then at least do this:

```py
for (x,y) in xy_coords:
    new_image[y,x] = 1
```

Or even more succinctly:

```py
(i,j) = np.where(mask1 > 0)
new_image[i,j] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The truth is that I do need the x and y coordinates since every pixel in new image has a different value (I was using 1 to simplify my question)

Comment: even in that case (per-pixel different value), you can use numpy to great profit. the third code block can be given a list of values to assign, if it's the same length ad the `i` and `j` lists. if numpy complains about shapes and broadcasting, that can be fixed by inserting a 1-sized dimension in the right place to satisfy numpy broadcasting rules.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is using a double loop, which combines all X values to all Y values and creates non-existing points.

E.g. from the two points (a, b) and (c, d), you would set (a, b), (c, b), (a, d), (c, d).

In addition, this is terribly slow: from N points you create N² of them.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. I am new in Python so I thought this was an appropriate approach. Indeed, this is slow. Can you suggest an alternative to the nested for loops?

Comment: @PPM: use the N points.